# Is there a way to pause mosh from 3 second UDP updates?

Tags: networking, cygwin, power-consumption, mosh

Is there a way to pause [mosh](http://ports.su/net/mosh) in a Cygwin installation?

I think it's causing an excessive battery drain for my AndroidAP phone, since it's designed to be sending packets every 3 seconds, which is not very helpful when the mosh window is minimised and not used for hours on end.

Comment: Did you try `Suspend Process` from the Windows Task Manager?

Comment: @DavidPostill, don't have such option in Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Ah. I haven't used the built-in task manager for many years. You can definately do it from [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - task manager replacement from sysinternals (part of MS) and [ProcessHacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) - which I am running and prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can [check out and use the `lowbandwidth` branch of mosh](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/commit/979c2a1cb7e61998f2b6ffec0b019167bd2be616), which will have 2 significant changes:

1. Change the acknowledgement interval from 3 seconds to 60 seconds
2. Tweak other settings so that 3 packets are sent per keystroke, instead of 4 packets.

Refer to [this mailing list posting](https://www.mail-archive.com/mosh-devel@mit.edu/msg00281.html) for more information.

SSH Timeout

Don't forget that the [SSH server keep-alive settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34201/29720), for example

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=3
```